# Cannot use command in child_process.spawn if its not in environment path?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to launch a command via NodeJS using the child_process.spawn() API.  It seems to work fine if I use any command that is part of the system's environment path, but it throws an error if the command is not in the environment path.  My application requires that it spawns a command process that is not, by default, part of the system environment.  I want to make my code portable and so I would like to avoid forcing the end-user to add a particular command to their environment path.

I'm first developing on macOS:

Here's what works:

```
var cmd_directory = "/Applications/My Application Directory/"; //contains spaces

child = spawn('ls', ['-lh'], { cwd : cmd_directory }, function(err, stdout, stderr){

    if (err) {
        console.log("\t\tProblem spawning command =>\n\t\t" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("\t\tSpawned new process successfully!")
    }

});
```

When running the above code, I get a directory listing of the `/Applications/My Application Directory`.

Now, if I want to run a command that exists in that same directory, I get a ENOENT error.  So, this code does not work:

```
var cmd_directory = "/Applications/My Application Directory/"; //contains spaces

child = spawn('myapp', ['-v'], { cwd : cmd_directory }, function(err, stdout, stderr){

    if (err) {
        console.log("\t\tProblem spawning command =>\n\t\t" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("\t\tSpawned new process successfully!")
    }

});
```

Why does this happen even though the working directory is set to the same location as where the command is?

Lastly, how can I make sure the `myapp` command spawns even if it does not exist in the system's or user's environment path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the suggestion made by Julian Goacher, which I could not get to work by simply adding the full path to the command.  Therefore I'm writing this answer for other who might encounter the same issue.

I solved it by adding the "PATH" key to the child_process.spawn() options object.  Here is the working code:

```
var child_options = {
      cwd : prj
    , env : {
                PATH: cmd_directory
            }
    , detatched : true
    , stdio     : 'ignore'
};

//Spawn a child process with child options and command line params
child = spawn('mycommand', arg_array, child_options, function(err, stdout, stderr){

    if (err) {
        console.log("\t\tProblem executing aerender =>\n\t\t" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("\t\tLaunched aerender successfully!")
    }

});

child.unfref() //To ensure child runs as its own process (async style)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try providing the full path to the command to the spawn function:

```
const path = require('path');
const cmd = path.join( cmd_directory, 'myapp' );
child = spawn( cmd , ['-v'], {}, ( .. ) => {
  ..
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunately it does not work.  I'm thinking it has to do now with the options object which contains a key name `env`.  I'm going to try that now and see if it works.  Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @ariestav It does work, I've used the same approach in my code for exactly  the same reason. Are you sure that 'myapp' has exec perms?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% it has exec permissions.  For the options object in the spawn method, I just used `{ cwd : cmd_directory, env: { PATH : cmd_directory} }` and it now works!  Maybe in your case the command was in Node's process.env path already?

Comment: Did the path have spaces in it?

Comment: I didn't in my original code, but I just did a test using a path with a space, calling a command (in this case, a bash script) which isn't on any path, and it worked fine for me. This is also on Mac OS.

Comment: Strange, the command I am using in question is not a bash script, but a command line executable.  Thank you again for the help!  Hopefully our short exchange will help folks in the future.